# Virtuemart2 csv import database keeps crashing

Tags: database, csv, import, crash, virtuemart

I'm using a plugin, **CSV Advanced**, to import about 230 products in Virtuemart 2. It all seemed to work well in the beginnig but the table **"_virtuemart_product_customfields"** keeps crashing. I have now tried importing just a few products at a time and it seems, however i do it, when I get up to about 151 products the table crashes. Even if I just try to import one more product.

I have "TRUNCATE":ed the table many times (**is this enough to get a "fresh start"?**) and started all over again.

I have not removed the products, I am just trying to update their short description, long description, custum fields and value for custom fields.

**I got this error in phpMyadmin when I analysed the table (after importing just one more product than 151):**

XXX_virtuemart_product_customfields / check / warning / Table is marked as crashed

XXX_virtuemart_product_customfields / check / error / Can't read indexpage from filepos: 33792

XXX_virtuemart_product_customfields / check / Error / Incorrect key file for table './XXX_virtuemart_product_customfields.MYI'; try to repair it

XXX_virtuemart_product_customfields / check / error / Corrupt

Anyone have any idea about what might be causing this? I really dont belive that there are any misstakes in my CSV-file.

Maybe worth mentioning, the information in the file is in swedish, with åäö, but the CSV is in UTF-8 format.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try To increase your mysql user query execution time
```

again this issue comes then You need to import as batch (put some limitations)